# How to avoid N+1 queries in Rails "each" loops?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In a todo list-style app, I have the following ActiveRecord model method:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def project_name
    project.tasks.length > 0 ? "#{project.name} - #{name}" : project.name
  end
end
```

The idea is to provide additional project information if there are one or more tasks on the project.

However, when invoked regularly on views this creates performance concerns (especially with a growing data set).

What is the best way to optimize this query so that it doesn't create N+1 query type issues when invoked from "each" loops in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Eager Loading in the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Basically you use the `includes` method to load all the tasks at once rather than the N+1 approach.

However for your example a better approach is to use [counter caching](http://www.elegantruby.com/Tutorials/2013/01/25/adding-a-counter-cache-for-fun-and-profit/). This pre-calculates the number of tasks that are referenced to each project. You're also breaking separation of concerns / 'tell, don't ask' a little by putting the `project_name` logic in the `Task` class, it should belong in the `Project` class:

```
class Task
  def project_name
    project.name(self)
  end
end


class Project
  def name(task = nil) 
    return read_attribute[:name] if task.nil?
    tasks_count > 0 ? "#{read_attribute[:name]} - #{task.name}" : read_attribute[:name]
  end
end
```